# Does Barvinok's algorithm apply to convex integer program?

Tags: computational-complexity, convex-optimization, integer-programming

Barvinok provided a counting algorithm to count number of integer solutions to integer linear program that runs in polynomial time if the number of integer variables is fixed.

If we have convex constraints instead of linear is there any such fixed dimension polynomial time counting algorithm?